# Excel VBA Simulating "Not In" SQL functionality

Tags: excel, vba

All -

I have a 2 sheet excel.

Sheet 1 is three columns (name, date, value)
Sheet 2 is name.

I want to write a VBA script that displays all of Sheet 1 data that does NOT have any of the name field listed in Sheet 2 anywhere in sheet 1 (name can appear in different columns so ideally it would search all cells in Sheet 1) to appear in sheet 3

See the sample image for a rough idea of what I"m hoping to accomplish.  I have searched but have not had luck.

[image: sample data]

Comment: `Range.AutoFilter` might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

You did not say where the source table and criteria table begin, or where to place the result of the "anti-filter". I wrote this code on the assumption that they all start at the first cell of the worksheet, A1:

```
Sub AntiFilter()
Dim aSource As Range, aCriteria As Range, oCell As Range, oTarget As Range, countCells As Long
    Set aSource = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    countCells = aSource.Columns.Count
    Set aCriteria = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set oTarget = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1")
    aSource.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=aCriteria, Unique:=False
    For Each oCell In Application.Intersect(aSource, aSource.Columns(1))
        If oCell.RowHeight < 1 Then
            oCell.Resize(1, countCells).Copy Destination:=oTarget
            Set oTarget = oTarget.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next oCell
    On Error Resume Next
    aSource.Worksheet.ShowAllData
    On Error GOTO 0
End Sub
```

[image: Demo Anti-Filter macro]

[Workbook with macro, test data and examples of selection criteria on Sheet2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yl3u5kuus6opzr0/Anti-filter.xlsm?dl=0)

If the macro does not work as expected, make sure that you have sheets named Sheet1, Sheet2, and Sheet3 in your workbook, and that the source data range and criteria range start with cells A1. If this is not the case, make the necessary changes to the text of the macro:
[image: EditMacro.png]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!  The pasting of the data is working well, but the anti-filter logic isn't actually removing anything, it just pastes the entirety of Sheet1 into Sheet3.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Amateurhour35  "I don’t have office 365" - perhaps this is the reason. Unlikely, but possible. What Excel do you have? Hopefully not 2003, your screenshot looks more modern.

Comment: QUick question, when running this in tandem with my other macros, I'm now getting this error: Run-time error '1004': Method 'ShowAllData' of object'_Worksheet' failed. Any idea why introducing this code triggered that?

Comment: @Amateurhour35 The point is that ShowAllData works well if there are hidden rows on the sheet (hidden manually or as a result of filtering). If there are no such lines, it is an error that you are writing about. The easiest and most reliable way is add `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0` around line `aSource.Worksheet.ShowAllData`

Comment: Not sure I follow -- There's no hidden rowsin the worksheet.   On Error Resume Next and On Error GoTo 0 shoudl go where?  In the VBA , it's highlighting the specific row of aSource.Worksheet.ShowAllData  , do I need to clear filters or something somehow?  Sorry for the newb-level questions

Comment: No, no, you don't have to go anywhere. These lines are simply "escaping" a possible error. The first one `On Error Resume Next` says - "whatever happens - continue the execution further, do not shout about the error, just work", and the second `On Error GoTo 0` says "if errors suddenly appear further, then report them as usual"

Comment: The same error unfortunately still appears.   It continues to highlight the aSource.Worksheet.ShowAllData

Comment: @Amateurhour35 Perhaps you did not understand my comment. I changed the code in the answer, added `On Error...` as it should be. I can't specify more precisely, I don't know the details of *"when running this in tandem with my other macros"*

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365 you can use the Dynamic Array formulas

```
=LET(Names,FILTER(Sheet1!$C:$E,Sheet1!$C:$C<>""),FILTER(Names,ISERROR(MATCH(INDEX(Names,,1),Sheet2!$G:$G,0))))
```

Example:

Data (Sheet1)

[image]

Exclusion List (Sheet2)

[image]

Result

[image]

<sub>Note: this excludes the headers because the header label `Name` is present in both the Data column and the Exclusion column so be sure to maintain that</sub>

Comment: Dang, that looks like formula wise it would have worked , but I don’t have office 365. I prefer vba because I have a second set of code that saves as csv in a specific directory, I’ve been trying to modify the original solution posted but not sure why that anti-filter solution isn’t working

Answer (score 0):

Without Excel 365. I'd recommend a UDF

```vb
Function FilterList(ByVal Data As Range, ByVal Exclusion As Range) As Variant
    Dim Res As Variant
    Dim Dat As Variant
    Dim Excl As Variant
    Dim rw As Long
    Dim idx As Long
    Dim cl As Long
    Dim ExcludeIt As Variant
    Dim Cols As Long
    Dim TopRow As Long
    
    ReDim Res(1 To Application.Caller.Rows.Count, 1 To Application.Caller.Columns.Count)
    
    If IsEmpty(Data.Cells(1, 1)) Then
        TopRow = Data.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
        Set Data = Data.Resize(Data.Rows.Count - TopRow).Offset(TopRow - 1)
    End If
    
    If IsEmpty(Data.Cells(Data.Rows.Count, 1)) Then
        Set Data = Data.Resize(Data.Cells(Data.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - Data.Row + 1)
    End If
    
    Dat = Data.Value
    Excl = Exclusion.Columns(1).Value
    
    Cols = Application.Min(UBound(Dat, 2), UBound(Res, 2))
    
    idx = 0
    For rw = 1 To UBound(Dat, 1)
        ExcludeIt = Application.Match(Dat(rw, 1), Excl, 0)
        If IsError(ExcludeIt) Then
            idx = idx + 1
            For cl = 1 To Cols
                Res(idx, cl) = Dat(rw, cl)
            Next
        End If
    Next
    For rw = 1 To UBound(Res, 1)
        For cl = IIf(rw <= idx, UBound(Dat, 2) + 1, 1) To UBound(Res, 2)
            Res(rw, cl) = vbNullString
        Next
    Next
    FilterList = Res
End Function
```

Enter it as an Array Formula (complete it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) in a range large enough to hold the returned data (can be larger), and pass it your input Data range and Exclusion range (both as whole columns)

```
=FilterList(Sheet1!$C:$E,Sheet2!$G:$G)
```