# VBA: Advanced Filter: How to filter by NON FOUND values in a list?

Tags: excel, vba

**What do I want to do?**
Filter values in ("Data") Sheet, Based on a list in ("Source") Sheet.

**What is my problem?**
I am able only to filter the "found values", I want to filter by "NON FOUND VALUES"

**What I have tried to do?**
Changed this *.AutoFilter Field:=1, **Criteria1:="="*** to this *.AutoFilter Field:=1, **Criteria1:="<>"***
Still nothing changed the same list appeared also

**This is my code**

```
 Dim tempCriteria As Variant
 Dim i As Long
 Dim Criteria() As String

 Dim LastRow As Integer
 LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source").UsedRange.Rows.Count
 Dim R As String
 R = "A2:A" & LastRow

 tempCriteria = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Source").Range(R)

 ReDim Criteria(1 To UBound(tempCriteria))

 For i = 1 To UBound(tempCriteria)
 Criteria(i) = CStr(tempCriteria(i, 1))
 
 Next


 With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range(R)
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Criteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With
```

Comment: Wait! What is `R`? Is it range on Data sheet from A2 to lastRow... where?! On Source sheet?! So, you filtered only part of Data table?

Comment: What do you think, the solution would be?

Comment: Why not? See [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64125789/14094617)

Comment: Thank you "JohnSUN" for the time taken to read my question, for your patience, for your knowledge shared, for your effort, for your understanding, and for your time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible solutions:

```
Sub byNonFound()
Dim aSource As Range, aCriteria As Range, oCell As Range, rToHide As Range
    Set aSource = Worksheets("Data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Set aCriteria = Worksheets("Source").Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    aSource.Worksheet.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
    aSource.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=aCriteria, Unique:=False
    For Each oCell In Application.Intersect(aSource, aSource.Columns(1)).Offset(1, 0)
        oCell.EntireRow.Hidden = Not oCell.EntireRow.Hidden
    Next oCell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It is assumed that the column headings in the source range and in the criteria range are the same (this is how Advanced Filter works)